# Refrencing connection file in multiple PHP scripts

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli, pdo

I am having some trouble understanding how to correctly reference the following connection file in multiple PHP scripts.

**DB Configuration File:**

**Config.php**

```
/**
 * Database config variables
 */
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "username");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "password");
define("DB_DATABASE", "dbName");
?>
```

**Connection File:**

**DB_Connect.php**

```
<?php
class DB_Connect {
    private $conn;

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'include/Config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        // return database handler
        return $this->conn;
    }
}

?>
```

**Connection Header of a PHP document:**

How should the connection header for the following PDO script be written:

```
<?php



{

  $options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
  ];

  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb;dbname=$namedb;charset=$charset", $userdb, $passdb, $options);

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `column1`
    FROM `Table1` ");

  $stmt->execute([]);

  $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  echo json_encode($row);
}

?>
```

Comment: Why are you using 2 different API types to connect with/used the same variable?

Answer (score 1):

First off, this class DB_Connect *makes absolutely no sense*. In theory it adds some abstract "abstraction" but in reality it's just useless piece of code.  So just get rid of it.

Then create a file named `pdo.php` and add the following code (based on my [How to connect to MySQL using PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql) canonical example):

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'dbname';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
try {
     $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

then *just include this file* in any script that requires a database interaction:

```
<?php

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/pdo.php';

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT `column1` FROM `Table1` ");
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Note that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` stuff. it is used to make your file available from any directory. it is explained in my other article on the [using correct filesystem paths](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths)

Answer (score -3):

```
class DB_PDO_Connect {
    private $db;

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {

        if(!isset($this->db)){
            require_once 'include/Config.php';

            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=DB_DATABASE;host=DB_HOST;", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,
                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_NATURAL );
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $this->db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING ); // debug
        }
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

use

```
$myPDO =new DB_PDO_Connect();
$conn=$myPDO->connect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `column1` FROM `Table1` ");
//...
```

Comment: Can you explain what it is you did in order to probably help solve what the question is about? That way, everyone wins.

Comment: trans Connection File mysqli to pdo ~

Comment: It does not seem to work, where should the class DB_PDO_Connect go?

Comment: Can you please explain how the PHP File references the DB_PDO_Connect() function? Should I do `require_once 'include/DB_Connect.php';`

Comment: I get the error: Fatal error</b>: Class 'DB_PDO_Connect' not found

Comment: @JenLarson DB_Connect this question is provided，
Use the same way as this problem, just replace the content with pdo